# App Store Connect Allow Developer Resources Checkbox When Adding User

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to add a User to my App Store Connect so they can upload a build, but in the portal it does not allow me to give them access to certificates as the checkbox stays greyed out. I am the Account holder and Admin. "Access 
to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" stays grey. Cant change this even when added as a User and try to edit their permissions.
[image]

Comment: To even further help those who liked [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2420677/mark)'s answer: [Here is an article](https://www.mobiloud.com/help/knowledge-base/convert-apple-developer-program-individual-to-organization) that describes the process of how to convert your account. And [here is an official Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/support/account) about this.
The procedure basically is that you have to contact Apple for such an Upgrade.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably because you have an `individual` account instead of `organization` one. I found it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/358562).

Hope this helps anyone like me who got stuck here.